# The method 'addItem' was called on null

Tags: list, flutter, mobile, methods

I have a problem with that situation. Can you help me ? I'm taking this error message.

Exception has occurred.

NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addItem' was called on null.
   Receiver: null
    Tried calling: addItem("{\"name\":\"example\",\"isCompleted\":false,\"isArchived\":false}"))

I'm using addItem here;

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff655c56),
          onPressed: () async {
            String itemName = await showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) => ItemDialog());

            if (itemName.isNotEmpty) {
              var item =
                  Item(name: itemName, isCompleted: false, isArchived: false);
              _itemService.addItem(item.toJson());

              setState(() {});
            }
          },
```

And I define addItem here;

```
Future<List<Item>> fetchItems() async {
    final response = await http.get(_serviceUrl);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Iterable items = json.decode(response.body);

      return items.map((item) => Item.fromJson(item)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('something went wrong');
    }
  }
  Future<Item> addItem(String itemJson) async{
    final response = await http.post(_serviceUrl, headers: {
      'content-type':'application/json'
    },body: itemJson);

    if(response.statusCode==201){
      Map item= json.decode(response.body);

      return Item.fromJson(item);
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('something went wrong');
    }
  }
}
```

HELPPPP!
fluter up to date btw

Comment: Please post your whole code

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try call `addItem` method on `_itemService` that not assigned to anything. But for more clear answer please share all codes relate this issue.